# Filter on lookup columns in quick edit list

Tags: list-view, quick-edit

We have a problem with filtered data in lookup columns in a list. For example.
We have three lists.
1.  Division

[image]

2. Band names

   [image]
3. Tracking Chart

   [image]

In third list division and brand names are lookup columns from list 1 and 2.
Now we need to filter “Brand names” drop-down in quick edit list according to the selected division.

Can you please advise how we can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

As far I know, quick edit is not supporting cascading drop down. Please check following link.

[Quick Edit Mode](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e7fa9b7c-d524-454a-b516-d280bf896ee3/quick-edit-mode-and-infopath-form?forum=sharepointcustomization)